# Can I refer to a closure in a different thread?

Tags: lua

As far as I know Lua uses closures to encapsulate local variables,
well I've got a function call in a worker thread which passes reference to a callback function, and the async call will be handled by the main thread, means callback will also execute on the main thread. My question is, because I don't know if accesses to closures are maintained by heap pointers or `_ENV` table, will I face any errors?

I have a main thread and a thread pool (pool of `pthread`s) which the main is responsible for pulling updates and pushing them into pool as jobs.

So far so good, but the problem is jobs sometimes need to call RPCs and the only thread which handles RPCs is the main one. So I pass this function call to main thread with a callback. But since job is done in the thread pool, this RPC call is wrapped inside a closure which contains vital variables that I need, so when callback is called, are they still accessible?

Finally if you know another solution which can help me in this please tell me, I'm using [torch7/threads](https://github.com/torch/threads)